# Preg_replace in PHP... replace & fillter text between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

this is my code: `<span>C</span>         <span>F</span>                <span>D</span>   Hello, this is a text from me. Song's lyric, I need to fix   <span>D </span>     <span>E</span>`

its wil from $text, and then preg_replace will run. and $text will be place in:

```
<pre>$text</pre>
```

To show like this:

```
<span>C</span>         <span>F</span>                <span>D</span>
Hello, this is a text from me. Song's lyric, I need to fix
<span>D</span>      <span>E</span>
```

I tried to use:

```
$text=preg_replace("/<\/span>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\'\"\!\@\&\s\(\)\[\]\-\_\+\=]{8}\s+/","<br></span>$1$2",$text);
```

But the result is:

```
<span>C<br></span><span>F<br></span> ...
```

Please help me on this one... >_< spend like hours to do it, hic
If have another way not use preg_replace, please show me too.

Comment: i don't entirely understand what you want to replace or change but anyway like i have learned the hard way, it's a bad thing to use regular expression for html tags. You should use html dom -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: not duplicated, differen. Between <pre></pre> tags, I want keep those space of Chord Music. And first 3 span is not <br> , only the text lyric <br>

Comment: @Gordon: Believe me, i'm helping a great deal mentioning he shouldn't waste his time with regex in this particular case. You are always free to try & fix the regex .. be my guest

Comment: Thansk krike, but I used simple HTML doom too, however it will remove all space when u use ->plainttext or innerhtml or outer also

Comment: Not a duplicate of that! And the Accepted Answer is wrong. Almost all Regular Expression engines used in todays programming languages are PCRE and can parse HTML given enough effort. The effort just isnt worth it most of the time, which is why you will want to use a parser.

Comment: @Ken le: there are other html dom parsers. Try a few different ones and see which one works the best. But don't waste your time on regex

Comment: I get a song lyrics from an XML database API. But it return no break line at al. So, I need to to code to break line for the lyric, but not break line for the music chord. And between music chord, have space to  show on right place on top of text line.

Comment: I found out a new way to do it already, phew, thanks God saving my day... and thanks u guys too.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to do something like: echo '<pre>'.$text.'</pre>'?

Comment: it's ok. I fixed it already. This one is really hard to understand >_< I got headache because of it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further reference I figured I might post what I came up with when solving this task using [PHP's DOM parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

I might add it was somewhat confusing that all the "real" nodes are in fact in the NodeList of not the document element, but the NodeList of the first child of the document element (that is *docElem -> first child -> children* instead of *docElement -> children*).

```
<?php
$str = '<span>f</span> <span>d</span> my text here lololol <span>t</span> <span>ok</span> dwa dawmo pgse gmspg mse <span>d</span>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$docElem = $doc->documentElement;
$children = $docElem->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes;

    for ($i = 0, $len = $children->length; $i<$len; $i++)
    {
        $node = $children->item($i);
        $val = trim($node->nodeValue);

            // text
            if (is_a($node, 'DOMText') && $val) {
                echo "<br />\r\n" . $val . "<br />\r\n";
            // span
            } else if ($node->tagName == 'span') {
                echo '<'. $node->tagName .'>' . $val . '</'. $node->tagName .'>';
            // whitespace
            } else {
                echo $node->nodeValue;
            }
    }

?>
```

This will output:

```
f d
my text here lololol
t ok
dwa dawmo pgse gmspg mse
d
```

of course with the html elements as well:

```
<span>f</span> <span>d</span><br />
my text here lololol<br />
<span>t</span> <span>ok</span><br />
dwa dawmo pgse gmspg mse<br />
<span>d</span>
```